# php how to get whole line after spicific character from text file?

Tags: php, arrays, readfile

I have text file

```
name,name1
willhaveishere1
name,name2
willhaveishere2
name,name3
willhaveishere3
```

i want read it and return like that

```
$nn = name1
$ss = willhaveishere1
```

with my code i get only name1

my code is

```
$file1 = "file.txt";
$file = file($file1);
$count = count($file);
if($count > 0) {
$i = 1;
foreach($file as $row) {
$n = strstr($row, 'name,');
$cc = array("name,");
$dd   = array("");
$nn = str_replace($cc, $dd, $n);
echo $nn;
$i++; } }
```

Comment: I don't really see what your goal is with this code

Comment: i want read text file by php to get name and line , code get only name i want to get line after name ,,,,,,???? to add to mysql

Comment: advice me with new code to get what i want , thank you

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need

```
if($count > 0) {
    foreach($file as $row) {
        $pos = strpos($row, ',');
        if($pos !== false){
            echo substr($row, $pos + 1);
            $nn[] = substr($row, $pos + 1);
        } else {
            echo $row;
            $ss[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Yes, just loop through, but make sure both `$nn` and `$ss` has same count, which is depending on your file.

Also Note: [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions has been deprecated, so please use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

```
$count = count($nn);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, line) VALUES('$nn[$i]', '$ss[$i]')"; mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

**EDIT 2**

try this example:

```
$file = array(
    0 => 'name,name1',
    1 => 'willhaveishere1',
    2 => 'name,name2',
    3 => 'willhaveishere2',
    4 => 'name,name3',
    5 => 'willhaveishere3'
);
$count = count($file);
if($count > 0) {
    foreach($file as $row) {
        $pos = strpos($row, ',');
        if($pos !== false){
            $nn[] = substr($row, $pos + 1);
        } else {
            $ss[] = $row;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
$count = count($nn);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, line) VALUES('$nn[$i]', '$ss[$i]');"; 
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Can i add to mysql database ? $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, line)
VALUES('$nn[]', '$ss[]')";
mysql_query($sql); ?????

Comment: i try to add to mysql but i cant because if($pos !== false){
            $nn[] = substr($row, $pos + 1);
        } else {
            $ss[] = $row;
        }

Comment: see my edit, you can loop through and can make it insert in mysql database

Comment: where add this code in main code ??   $count = count($nn);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, line) VALUES('$nn[$i]', '$ss[$i]')"; mysql_query($sql); 
}

Comment: after the foreach ends

`foreach($file as $row) {
        $pos = strpos($row, ',');
        if($pos !== false){
            echo substr($row, $pos + 1);
            $nn[] = substr($row, $pos + 1);
        } else {
            echo $row;
            $ss[] = $row;
        }
    }
   $count = count($nn);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, line) VALUES('$nn[$i]', '$ss[$i]')"; mysql_query($sql); 
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82683/discussion-between-kamal-pal-and-espoo).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this straightforward method:

```
if($fh = fopen("file.txt","r")){ 
    $nameBefore = false;

    //loop through every line of your file
    while (!feof($fh)){ 
        $line = fgets($fh);

        //check if the name was detected in previous line
        if ($nameBefore !== false)
        {
            //you have the set of name and line, do what you want
            echo $nameBefore . ': ' . $line . '<br />';
            $nameBefore = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //see if the line is made of two coma separated segments and the first one is 'name'
            //Remember the name for the next line
            $parts = explode(',', $line);
            if (count($parts) == 2 && $parts[0] == 'name')
                $nameBefore = $parts[1];
        }
    } 
    fclose($fh); 
}
```

Comment: i get what i want but i want to add them to mysql ... ?

Comment: you have both values in variables. just add them to your insert/update query instead of echo.

Comment: Assuming that you already have mysql connection resource replace the echo line with the insert/update one: mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO \`tablename\` (\`name\`, \`data\`) VALUES ('$nameBefore','$line')");

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use strpos to find the first occurrence of the character in the line, and if found remove everything from the line before that position. This way you are left with only the part of the line you are interested in.

Code:

```
$character = ',';
$fileHandle = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fileHandle)) {

    // Retrieve the line from the file
    $line = fgets($fileHandle);

    // If the line contains the character
    // Remove everything before the character
    $charPos = strpos($line, $character);
    if ($charPos !== false) {
        $line = substr($line, $charPos + 1);
    }

    // Do something with the remainder of the line
    echo $line . PHP_EOL;
}

fclose($fileHandle);
```

Output:

```
name1
willhaveishere1
name2
willhaveishere2
name3
willhaveishere3
```

If you wish to retrieve the following line, simply do another retrieve line call in your loop:

```
while (!feof($fileHandle)) {

    // Retrieve two lines in one loop iteration
    $lineOne = fgets($fileHandle);
    $lineTwo = fgets($fileHandle);
}
```

Making sure to only apply the comma replace part on the first line. This can lead to problems though if your data is... inconsistent.

Hope this helps.